# How to pass sequential data into a navigationBarTitle in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, master-detail, dataflow

I have a master-detail app that starts with a list of Users -> Their Cities -> Their Towns. The content of the views is working fine, but I can't figure out how to adjust my data flow so that the .navigationBarTitle reflects the previously selected item. e.g. if I pick user "jimmy" I want "jimmy" to be the title over the list of cities.

Here is my data model:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let cities: [CityModel]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case cities
    }
}

struct CityModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let towns: [TownModel]
}

struct TownModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

Here is my root view, UserList.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(userData) { user in
                NavigationLink(destination: CityList(cities: user.cities)) {
                    UserRow(user: user)
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Users"))
        }
    }
}

struct UserList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UserList()
    }
}
```

And here is the CityList.swift clicking a user is opening:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CityList: View {
    var thisUser: UserModel
    var cities: [CityModel]

    var body: some View {
        List (cities) { city in
            NavigationLink(destination: TownList(towns: city.towns)) {
               CityRow(city: city)

            }.navigationBarTitle(Text(self.thisUser.firstName))
        }
    }
}
```

The error is thrown on the following line of UserList.swift, because it's calling to CityList but isn't account for CityList's reference of "thisUser". Only I'm not sure what the correct syntax is to adjust it.

```
NavigationLink(destination: CityList(cities: user.cities)) { UserRow(user: user) }

ERROR: Missing argument for parameter 'thisUser' in call
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the user to `CityList` just as you passed the list of cities.

The error message is telling you that you're missing one of the parameters for the memberwise initializer that `CityList` automatically receives.  The memberwise initializer takes all of the struct's properties and, I believe, in the order in which they're declared in the struct.

```
NavigationLink(destination: CityList(thisUser: user, cities: user.cities)) { UserRow(user: user) }
```